# Flash / ActionScript - playing video question

Tags: flash, actionscript, flv

Could you please test if the demo on the *main page* of http://flvplayerlite.com/ does correctly handle the fast rewind *(the button to the left)*.

I know this may sound absurd, but for me it works fine in **Chrome**, but fails in **Firefox**.

The "failure" is that the video rewinds to the first available keyframe, but can't rewind further.

---

Also, if someone could explain why could this happen, I would appreciate that. *I basically think the rewinding is done somehow like:*

```
ns.seek(ns.time - k);  // where 'k' could be something like '1' or '2'
                       // and 'ns' stands for the 'NetStream' used to play video.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about problems existing in Firefox (tested on 3.6.9).  Interesting to note, however, that the left arrow key (on the keyboard) does work do do the rewind... though it does 'hiccup' a bit at the same key frames the UI arrow stops at.

If the UI arrow is clicked quickly enough, the rewind will continue past the key frame, just as it does with holding the left arrow.  I will take a look at the source and see if anything jumps out at me.

**EDIT**
Did not realize this was a compiled swf and not open-source.  I would try to file a bug report with the creators. [contact link](http://flvplayerlite.com/contact/)

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error in Safari.  My debug log shows "NetStream.Seek.InvalidTime" entries.  I would guess there is something wrong with the way the seek time is calculated, so that the actual call is ns.seek(NaN) or a negative value, since ns.seek(0) should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine with
- Chrome 8.0.552.224, Flash Player: 10,1,51,95;
- FF 3.6.13, Flash Player: 10,1,53,64;
- IE 8, Flash Player: 10,1,51,95

Maybe it is the Flash Player? I am not sure but I had issues with streaming and progressive playing with Flash Player 10. And also it happened with Firefox and Safari only.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed to work fine in Opera 11.0 =)

Answer (score 0):

Here in both browsers, Chrome and Firefox the rewind option seems to work, I'm on FF version 3.6.13

Answer (score 0):

Work fine in chrome 8.0.5x and ff 3.6.13

Maybe because you need the latest flash player for your browser